# Passing data as an object from React.js(Client) to Rails_API(local server)

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, rest, client-server

i'm trying to send an object to my server controller as a post action as the following,

It throws an error that the params are nil, using binding.pry i also verified that the params that are passed are :nil,
I pretty sure the issue is in my syntax, but i tried several ways and still same error.

Can somebody help ?

```
function Metrics() {
  const [purchase, setPurchase] = useState({});
  const [income, setIncome] = useState({});
  const [expenses, setExpenses] = useState({});
  const [loan, setLoan] = useState({});
  const [equity, setEquity] = useState({});
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  const [metrics, setMetrics] = useState({
    purchaseComp: false, 
    incomeComp: false,
    equityComp: false,
    loanComp: false,
    expensesComp: false
  })

  const runMetrics = () => {
    let reportObj = {
      purchase_price: purchase,
      monthly_rent: income.rent,
      annual_rent_appreciation: income.appreciation,
      annual_property_taxes: expenses.propertyTaxes,
      annual_property_repairs: expenses.propertyRepairs,
      annual_vacancy_rate: expenses.propertyVacancyRate,
      loan_years: loan.years,
      loan_rate: loan.rate,
      exit_year: equity.exitPoint,
      property_appreciation: equity.appreciation
      
    }
    console.log(reportObj)
    let url = "http://localhost:3000/reports"
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          // "Accept": "application/json",
          'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({report: {reportObj}})
      } 
    )
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    
  }
```

My backend controller looks like this:

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        reports = Report.all
        render json: reports
    end

    def show
        report = Report.find(params[:id])
        render json: report
    end

    def create
        # binding.pry
        report = Report.create(report_params)
        render json: report
    end

    private
    def report_params
        params.require(:report).permit(:purchase_price, :monthly_rent,
                                        :annual_rent_appreciation, :annual_property_taxes, 
                                        :annual_property_repairs, :annual_vacancy_rate,
                                         :loan_years, :loan_rate,
                                         :exit_year, :property_appreciation
                                        )
    end


end
```

My cors is enabling all data ( i think):

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'

    resource '*',
      headers: :any,
      methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
  end
end
```

And my routes are:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html


  resources :properties
  resources :reports
end
```

The error that i'm getting in my terminal is :

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: report):

app/controllers/reports_controller.rb:21:in `report_params'
app/controllers/reports_controller.rb:15:in `create'
```

And the error in the console is :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaOEe.jpg)

///EDITED:

the data is being passed to the server, however it does not save the record- i have no idea why,
Can anyone help with this issue ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66d5G.png)

Don't understand why the id is null, what am i doing wrong?

The frontEnd still gives me the following erorr:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSCjL.png)

Comment: The `id` is null because there are validation errors. See what `Report.create!(report_params)` throws.

Comment: @razvans thank you !!!, it did work,

Problem was that i already declared an association Report belongs_to User, however my  User table is not set up yet,
Thanks again !